# Nikon D750 NEF files display incorrectly

Tags: nikon, lightroom, raw, rawtherapee, nikon-d750

I got some raw files from a friend who uses the same camera model as me (Nikon D750). I notice that whereas I can postprocess my NEF pictures just fine, his pictures look very very weird when I try to open them (the integrated NEF thumbnails look ok, but that's it). He confirmed that he also cannot edit his pictures in anything else but Lightroom.

Can you help me figure out what's going on? I assume there's some setting in the camera that scrambles the channels in some way only Lightroom can make sense of?

Here's a screenhsot of RawTherapee trying to open the file:
[image]

And [this](http://chymera.eu/photo/blog/nd750_nikitaD_a0862.NEF) (*warning: 24 MB file*) is the NEF file from the screenshot above.

Comment: Are your RAW files 12 or 14 bit? 12 bit does not work very well in RawTharapee. There is a good thread at `http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60645/why-are-my-nef-photos-unusually-dark-in-rawtherapee` that covers this question extensively.

Comment: This file opens fine in Windows Photo Viewer and with Photoshop CC 2015 on a Windows Computer.

Comment: @Gmck If you don't use backticks, URLs will actually be clickable... http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60645/why-are-my-nef-photos-unusually-‌​dark-in-rawtherapee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my NEF photos unusually dark in RawTherapee?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60645/why-are-my-nef-photos-unusually-dark-in-rawtherapee)

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem initially when I started with an older Photoshop version. I upgraded to Photoshop CC and installed the latest version of the Adobe Camera RAW plugin (ACR) which solved the problem. ACR must be at least version 8.7 or later.

Comment: Lighroom is working fine, and so ACR presumably is okay. Other software, like RawTherapee (pictured running under GNOME) doesn't. And RawTherapee definitely doesn't use ACR.